# ADD COLUMN with DEFAULT value to a huge table

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql DB and a table with   almost billion of rows.
when I try to add a new column with default value:

```
ALTER TABLE big_table
ADD COLUMN some_flag integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

The transaction goes on for 30+ min .. and the DB logs starts to shoots warnings.

Any way to optimize the query ?

Comment: what warnings to you see in the logfile?

Comment: You can create a copy of your table with its data, add the column to that, then swap the two tables by renaming them.  (You may have to handle the dependencies appropriately.)

Comment: @dezso we are talking for 1 billion rows busy table ...
how is duplicating it going to make the procedure faster / better

Comment: @d.raev dezso might be right ( [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13779061/318174) ) because of  the nature of Postgres WAL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides doing it in batches (which will still take a while):

You could dump the table as [**COPY**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html) statements and write a script to edit the contents of the COPY statements to insert another column (COPY can be CSV IIRC).

Then you just reload your altered `COPY` dump and it should in theory be faster than the `ALTER` because COPY will not log transactions.

The other option is to turn off [`fsync`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/wal-configuration.html) while you run the command... just remember to turn it back on.

You can also do both of the above in batches.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for more query construction trick but it seems there is non. I will consider the Fsync next time.

Comment: At the end of the day a billion is a billion. It's not a small number :) .  I am curious what the data is?

Comment: it represents parsed data from RL documents. For sure there is a better storage concept but changing the whole structure is not an option.

Comment: Not a critique on implementation choices. I was just curious as I'm always interested in how people are using stuff in the "real world".

Answer (score 13):

Starting from PostgreSQL 11 this behaviour will change.

[Waiting for PostgreSQL 11 – Fast ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN with a non-NULL default](https://www.depesz.com/2018/04/04/waiting-for-postgresql-11-fast-alter-table-add-column-with-a-non-null-default/):

> So, for the longest time, when you did:
>
> ```
> alter table x add column z text;
> ```
>
> it was virtually instantaneous. Get a lock on table, add information about new column to system catalogs, and it's done.
>
> But when you tried:
>
> ```
> alter table x add column z text default 'some value';
> ```
>
> then it took long time. How long it did depend on size of table.
>
> **This was because postgresql was actually rewriting the whole table, adding the column to each row, and filling it with default value.**
>
> *"What happens if you want to set the column to NOT NULL also? Are we back to the slow version in that case or does this handle that as well?"*
>
> **not null doesn’t change anything. it is a constraint for new rows. so adding a column with “not null default ‘xxx'” will be fast.**

Answer (score 6):

I'd consider creating the column without the default and manually updating the rows in batches with intermittent commits to apply the default.

Comment: Was thinking for the same but this will be probably take more time at the end. And i need to put it in a "version update" transaction .. so I m looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: One way or another all rows need to be copied to get a non-null value into the new column. You can do it all at once, blocking out other access while it happens, by specifying the default in `ALTER TABLE`. You can do it incrementally while other processes access the table by adding the column as null-capable and doing a series of small updates, possibly with a sleep between iterations. Don't do it in one big `UPDATE` for the whole table or you will bloat the table.

Comment: For this to be most effective, you'd also need to VACUUM between each batch.